# XAMPP Apache server not working on internal network

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp

(I asked this at stackoverflow, but was told it'd be better suited here...)

I have XAMPP installed on my local laptop (Vista) and it works fine. Apache and MySQL are running as services, and I can get to both //localhost/ and //192.168.2.2/ without any hassles.

However, if I try accessing the server from another laptop on my internal network by typing in the //192.168.2.2/ ip address, it <del>errors</del>times out. What am I missing here?

When I run Port Check, I get the following:

```
Service              Port   Status
==============================================================================
Apache (HTTP)          80   Program: C:\xampp\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Apache (WebDAV)        81   free
Apache (HTTPS)        443   Program: C:\xampp\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe

MySQL                3306   Program: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
\mysqld.exe
```

and when I try telnetting to localhost port 80, that works too. My httpd-vhosts.conf file contains the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.2.2>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, it times out, not errors out. I'm trying to get the Windows Firewall set up properly right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you open the port 80 in the Windows (or other) firewall on the server laptop.

Comment: That was it. To fix this, I opened Windows Firewall, clicked Change settings, went to the Exceptions tab, and then "Add Port". Thanks.

Comment: Good, glad I helped.